# Como regresar a un JFrame anterior con los cambios que habia hecho en esa ventana? Java

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

Tengo una JFrame "Botones" con algunos JToggleButtons, digamos que marco 3 de ellos y luego continuo al siguiente JFrame "Informacion" y me muestra los 3 botones que pulsé, hasta ahi todo bien, pero el problema es que cuando regreso al JFrame "Botones" los 3 botones estan sin pulsar, quisiera que los botones sigan marcados. Por favor si alguien me ayuda con esto, gracias.

**En el JFrame "Botones" hay un JButton "Continuar" y tiene este codigo**

```java
private void btnContinuarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        Informacion info = new Informacion();
        info.setVisible(true);
        this.setVisible(false);
    }
```

**En el JFrame "Informacion" hay un JButton "Regresar" y tiene este codigo**

```java
private void btnRegresarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        Botones B = new Botones();
        B.setVisible(true);
        this.setVisible(false);
    }
```

Comment: Posiblemente no estás regresando al mismo JFrame, sino que estás creando y mostrando otra instancia y da la impresión de que es la misma ventana. Edita la pregunta y agrega parte del código para poder ayudarte. [ask] [example]

Comment: Tienes razon, acabo de agregar el codigo que utilicé gracias.

Comment: Tu problema es que estás creando un nuevo JFrame al intentar regresar, Botones B = new Botones(); esa línea, por eso dice new, si quieres regresar al anterior, debes guardar la instancia que creas primero, y luego solo volver a ponerla visible.